# How to get number of consecutive days from current date using postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I want to get the number of consecutive days from the current date using Postgres SQL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVttO.png)

Above is the scenario in which I have highlighted consecutive days count should be like this.

Below is the SQL query which I have created but it's not returning the expected result

```
with grouped_dates as (
  select user_id, created_at::timestamp::date, 
         (created_at::timestamp::date - (row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at::timestamp::date) || ' days')::interval)::date as grouping_date
  from watch_history
)
select * , dense_rank() over (partition by grouping_date order by created_at::timestamp::date) as in_streak
from grouped_dates where user_id = 702
order by created_at::timestamp::date
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

If anyhow we can able to apply distinct for created_at field to below query then I will get solutions for my issue.

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT user_id,
  (created_at::timestamp::date - (row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at::timestamp::date) || ' days')::interval)::date as next_day
  FROM watch_history
)
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS number_of_consecutive_days
  FROM list
 WHERE next_day IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Does anyone have an idea how to apply distinct to `created_at` for the above mentioned query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "number of consecutive days" for the same user_id :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT user_id
     , array_agg(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '1 day' FOLLOWING) AS consecutive_days
  FROM watch_history
)
SELECT user_id, count(DISTINCT d.day) AS number_of_consecutive_days
  FROM list
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(consecutive_days) AS d(day)
 WHERE array_length(consecutive_days, 1) > 1
 GROUP BY user_id
```

To get the list of "consecutive days" for the same user_id :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT user_id
     , array_agg(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '1 day' FOLLOWING) AS consecutive_days
  FROM watch_history
)
SELECT user_id
     , array_agg(DISTINCT d.day ORDER BY d.day) AS list_of_consecutive_days
  FROM list
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(consecutive_days) AS d(day)
 WHERE array_length(consecutive_days, 1) > 1
 GROUP BY user_id
```

full example & result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=caf225d33a1c68bf09f1b2cc272f1797)

Comment: Getting an error "ERROR: RANGE FOLLOWING is only supported with UNBOUNDED Position: 108; SQLState: 0A000" @Edouard

Comment: it sounds strange ... what is your postgres version ? `RANGE BETWEEN '1 day' PRECEDING AND '10 days' FOLLOWING` is an example coming from the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

Comment: I'm using AWS RDS so in that the version of Postgres is 13.4

Comment: I have edited the question summary please check if you have solutions for that @Edouard

Comment: @Parth Shah : I have implemented a full example in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3798cdf1218a5ccc3336200be6a6f992) and it works well ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check it my side why range throwing an error